# Which method is better: Python SDK (server side) or JavaScript SDK (client-side) to add to and update cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Django web application with a postgresql database on an AWS server. 
I want to keep this database in sync with a nosql cloud firestore database. We're using cloud firestore as the backend for a mobile app.
This means that every form update or new object that is added to the web app needs to be in sync with cloud firestore.

I'm able to update cloud firestore using the Python SDK when each form is submitted via the web app. However, I want to know if this is the best method to keep these two databases in sync. Each time a form is submitted, I have to import the firebase SDK, and then use the methods to update cloud firestore. Obviously, this will take time, but I'm unsure if this method is better, or if using the JavaScript SDK will be better. In essence, which method will perform better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you are doing that from python SDK the read and write to cloud fire storage is done from the server means if you have x request and y number of users doing that, your server has to do x*y request to Cloudflare storage. in this case, your transaction from the server will be heavily based on a user basis but you can use admin SDK in python and give only admin to access to DB.
2. If you want to use js for the same then request will be shared by users and the server will be free but each user should have access to DB write and read, you have to be more careful about authenticating users.

so if its all read requests and user-based filters are done well use from js, if you have doubts on authentications or you don't want to take a risk in that use from python.